# How to transpile npm module with "optional chaining" code to earlier version of node?

Tags: node.js, webpack, transpiler

Currently I am running node v16.13.1 and I wrote small npm package I would like to publish to npm and then install globally and run as executable.

Application works fine when built with current version but because I am using "optional chaining" (object?.something) it does not work with node 12.

I do not want to change code, but I would like to transpile it so it runs it in all node versions between 12 and 16+.

My webpack look like this:

```js
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    console.log('Log::', env, argv);
    const config = {
        entry: './src/index.js',
        devtool: (argv.mode === 'development') ? 'cheap-module-source-map' : undefined,
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
            filename: 'bundle.js',
        },
        experiments: {
            outputModule: true,
        },
        plugins: [
            //empty pluggins array
            new webpack.BannerPlugin({ banner: "#!/usr/bin/env node", raw: true }),
        ],
        module: {
            // https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/#root
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /.m?js$/,
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                }
            ],
        },
        resolve: {
            fallback: {
                "fs": false,
                "path": false,
                "os": false,
                assert: require.resolve('assert'),
                path: require.resolve('path-browserify'),
                util: require.resolve('util'),
            },
        },
        target: "node12.22"
    };

    console.log('Log::', config);
    return config;
}
```

and this is .babelrc

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "targets": {
                    "esmodules": true
                }
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

running `npm build` with `target: "node"`  gives following error:

**Error: For the selected environment is no default ESM chunk format available:
ESM exports can be chosen when 'import()' is available.**

running it with `target: "node12.22"` does not give any errors but when I try to run I get:

**SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
←[90m    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)←[39m**

If I remove `target:"node"` all together I am getting following error when run:

**TypeError: s.existsSync is not a function**

If I run it without `fallback: { "fs": false` then I get compile errors:

**Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in**

Comment: How about adding `"type": "module"` to package.json? while keeping `node12.22` in weback

Comment: Another alternative as I suspect this is a babel issue `{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets":{"node":"12"},
      }
    ]
  ]
}
`

Comment: @pacifica94 tried both before none worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your Webpack config to have the optimizer output code that's compatible with ECMA 6, which does not include optional chaining:

```js
optimization: {
  minimizer: [
    new TerserPlugin({
      terserOptions: {
        ecma: 6,
        mangle: false,
        // compress: false, // NOTE: Not certain you can just pass false here, but I think probably
      },
    }),
  ],
},
```

And be sure to install the TerserJS Plugin and require it in your config, `const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');`